# How can I set customer company , city and state information in register success email in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, adminhtml, email-templates

how can I set customer company , city and state information in transport mail template when customer register successfully.
I try this one but they not working.

```
<p class="greeting">{{trans "Business Name :   %company" company=$customer.company}}</p>
<p class="greeting">
{{trans "Business Location :    %city," city=$customer.city}}{{trans "%state" state=$customer.state}}
</p>
```

[image]

how can I archive this can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things.

1. From the admin, Create the new template for the registration and added the new variable what ever you want.
2. Now override the magento function which send that email into your custom extension.
3. Now in the override file, first you need to set those variable value.
4. Now run all the magento commands again and then check by registering.